# Removing duplicate objects and summing field values

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, iteration

I am trying to remove duplicate objects from an `ArrayList` and sum the values of a certain field. For example:

If I have an `ArrayList` of object "Hardware":

```
{[Name: Ram, Quantity: 2], 
 [Name: Keyboard, Quantity: 3],
 [Name: Mouse, Quantity: 5],
 [Name: Keyboard, Quantity 5]}
```

I want to write a function that will find a duplicate and sum the quantities. In this case Keyboard is a duplicate so the final `ArrayList` should look like:

```
{[Name: Ram, Quantity: 2],
 [Name: Keyboard, Quantity: 8],
 [Name: Mouse, Quantity: 5]}.
```

I have made an attempt at it, and it seems to work sometimes, but sometimes it misses elements.

```
    List<Hardware> myList = new ArrayList<Hardware>();
    myList.add(new Hardware("Ram", 2);
    myList.add(new Hardware("Keyboard", 3);
    myList.add(new Hardware("Mouse", 5);
    myList.add(new Hardware("Keyboard", 5);

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
         Hardware current = list.get(i);
        for(int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++){
            Hardware compare = list.get(j);
            if(current.getName().equals(compare.getName)){
                 current.setQuantity(current.getQuantity()
                                   + compare.getQuantity())
                 list.remove(compare);
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You don't want to increment `j` if you've removed the item; it will cause you to skip the immediately following item.
- You don't want to start the second loop at `1`, you want to start it at `i+1`, because you don't need to check any of the prior elements.
- Your example has a few syntax errors, you change `myList` to `list` and you`re missing some parentheses and a semicolon

Try this instead:

```
List<Hardware> list = new ArrayList<Hardware>();
list.add(new Hardware("Ram", 2));
list.add(new Hardware("Keyboard", 3));
list.add(new Hardware("Mouse", 5));
list.add(new Hardware("Keyboard", 5));
list.add(new Hardware("Mouse", 1));

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  Hardware current = list.get(i);
  for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
    Hardware compare = list.get(j);
    if (current.getName().equals(compare.getName())) {
      current.setQuantity(current.getQuantity() + compare.getQuantity());
      list.remove(compare);
      j--;
    }
  }
}
```

---

You should also check out this link to help you with future problems like this one:

- [**How to debug small programs**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that you wrote O(n*n) algoritm 
It works fine only when `list.size()` is small. You may get O(n) performance here:

```
 Map<String, Hardware> hardwareMap = new HashMap<>();
 for(Hardware h : myList){
    Hardware current = hardwareMap.get(h.getName());
    if(current == null){
        hardwareMap.put(h.getName(), h);
    }else{
        current.setQuantity(current.getQuantity() + h.getQuantity());
    }
 }
 Collection<Hardware> list = hardwareMap.values();
```